# Finding number of elements in an array using a static variable

Tags: java, arrays, scope, static, global-variables

I'm working on a project for a vehicle info system. I have stored all the instances in an array and I have to print out the number of elements/instances I have in it using a static variable. I tried the code below but I kept getting 0 I guess because it references the count defined in the class (which is initialized to 0) instead of the count in the constructor which has the total number of instances. How can I fix this?

```
package edu.uga.cs1302.vehicles;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class vehicleInstancesAndMenu {
static int count;
    
public vehicleInstancesAndMenu() {
    menu();
}//constructor

public void vehicles() {
    Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[15];
    vehicles[0] = new Airplane("Airbus A220-100", "Delta Airlines", "2019", 2, 120, 300, 221, 250);
    vehicles[1] = new Airplane("Airbus A319-100", "Delta Airlines", "2018", 2, 200, 450, 319, 300);
    vehicles[2] = new Airplane("Airbus A320-200", "Delta Airlines", "2018", 2, 220, 500, 320, 320);
    
    vehicles[3] = new Automobile("Corolla LE", "Toyota", "2020", 300, 6, 150);
    vehicles[4] = new Automobile("Civic SE", "Honda", "2018", 310, 6, 160);
    vehicles[5] = new Automobile("Sentra", "Nissan", "2019", 360, 6, 200);
    
    vehicles[6] = new Ship("APM - Maersk", "Maersk", "1904", 400000, "Carnival",2695, 35);
    vehicles[7] = new Ship("MSC", "Mediterranean Shipping Company", "1970", 30000 ,"Mediterranean Shipping Company",2565, 32);
    vehicles[8] = new Ship("COSCO", "China Ocean Shipping Company", "1990", 650000, "China Ocean Shipping Company",36201, 40);
    
    vehicles[9] =  new Tesla("Tesla Model 3", "Tesla", "2020", 1, 250, 200, 6, 300);
    vehicles[10] = new Tesla("Tesla Model S", "Tesla", "2020", 1, 300, 220, 6, 390);
    vehicles[11] = new Tesla("Tesla Model Y", "Tesla", "2020", 1, 400, 360, 6, 420);
    
    vehicles[12] = new BatMobile("Model A","Wayne Industries", "2020", 4 , 300, 600 , 40000, "Wayne Industries", 500, 320);
    vehicles[13] = new BatMobile("Model C", "Wayne Industries", "2019", 3 , 290, 400, 32000, "Wayne Industries", 450, 310);
    vehicles[14] = new BatMobile("Model T", "Wayne Industries", "2018",3 , 250, 360, 280000, "Wayne Industries", 370, 310);

for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++) {
        count = vehicles.length;
    //System.out.println(vehicles[i] ); 
}//for
    System.out.println(count);
    }//vehicles

public void menu() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response;
    
    System.out.println("Welcome! \n1 - To see how many vehicles are in the system\n2 - To see the name and the class of each vehicle\n3 - To see which vehicles can fly.\n4 - To see which vehicles can float.\n5 - To see which vehicles can fly and float.\n6 - To see a description of each vehicle.\nh - to see brief help information for your system.\nq - To terminate the program.");
        response = scan.nextLine();
    
    switch(response) {
        case "1":
            if(response.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println(vehicleInstancesAndMenu.count);
            }
    }
}






}//vehicleInstancesAndMenu
```

Comment: There is no need for a loop to add to count, you could just set `count = vehicles.length;` outside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this by including `vehicle();`  in the `menu()` function, somewhere before your `System.out.println('..');` line. Currently the function is never being called so it isn't counting up anything. And instead of using a loop in the `vehicle()` function, just set `count = vehicles.length;` as stated in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where are you using a loop to get the count. Below is the code which give you count 15 for every reason. using different constructor or using class name.

public class HelloWorld {

static int  count = 0;

```
public HelloWorld() { 
    String[] strs = new String[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        strs[i] = "Some String _ " + i;
    }
    count = strs.length;
    System.out.println("Cons: " + count);
}

public HelloWorld(int x) { 
    System.out.println("Cons: " + count);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloWorld();
    System.out.println("In main-" + count);
    new HelloWorld(10);
    System.out.println("Using Class name : " + HelloWorld.count);
}
```

}

***Output***
Cons: 15
In main-15
Cons: 15
Using Class name : 15